# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type but the type exists

Tags: typescript, object, types, apexcharts

strange issue, I get the above mentioned error and I can't figure out why, here's a screenshot showing everything: [image]

Here's my code:

```
const createSeries = (report: ReportEntry[], key: string) => {
  const reportEntryValues: any = [];
  let itemColor: string;
  let series: ApexAxisChartSeries;

  report.forEach((item: ReportEntry) => {
    reportEntryValues.push(item[key as keyof typeof item]);
  });

  switch (key) {
    case "approved":
      itemColor = Colors.Green;
      break;
    case "denied":
      itemColor = Colors.Red;
      break;
    default:
      itemColor = Colors.Blue;
  }

  series = {
    name: key,
    type: "bar",
    color: itemColor,
    data: reportEntryValues,
  };

  return series
};
```

any help is hugely appreciated, I've been googling why this happens, the code works just fine but typescript is still screaming at me.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBVDtSpEVYVVZCADCDjIqGI3wo+lAAF5QABvRQlTgMZAAfnyV1QlE4zH5aHaovFkulJQQ0HgZHlgglwxl3DqDEKJRKAB9QAAKTjsRDSb6gE0W6DQACUAG0ALoy428j2GkqrMVmPAAbm9Prw-s4QZDhuSmOg9PgqvVYs1iuDPp9Kfg8Ug8cTGq1UrT6ZKyFQDHlAaLxeY8AY0EEFYjVcNAF83d6Tc6LVbvvxu9bsXaotBXe2fZ3+72zZPB-1hy7XaPXcG2+7FAhOJqTJMFKzKBzuabHWKKtTaQymSy2QeAHxe4IlJyofFePk+wXIMUAcmwDvgX94b0KSIMUACJpEcUDAJ9FU1TAgBiRFkig71dTLMVnQARn4AAmfgAGZ3RKFsVyLIA)

Comment: It can be that `name` in the `ApexAxisChartSeries`  type has non-English characters. Characters that look regular, but have different utf-8 codes. Can you check for it?

Comment: Also, you can compile a minimal working example at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play so it is easier to debug your problem.

Comment: @Paprika I just checked with https://onlineutf8tools.com/validate-utf8, everything seems to be fine :/

Comment: @Paprika I just updated the post with the link at the bottom here's a shortened url: shorturl.at/dmBQU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ApexAxisChartSeries` is an Array type. So you ether need to change the `ApexAxisChartSeries` to be an Object or return an array.

[Playground with solutions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgpAeN4EsDOBhAFgQwE7AGUJdkJUoBeKAbwCgooA7bAWwgH4AuKVYExgOa0AvgG0AurVoBjAPaNeUabgjZgEIiTKUoACgCU3OBEQoMOfJtLkKAPhr0oK4AFdcjBwwbM23AOSYEAA2QbJ+ADSOwgDcIrG0APQJPLJBLsDI8lAAjLSgkLAISGhYeITE1gBMOnTerBzcvPxCYpIy8orKqupWZNVUBkZFZqWWFX2U9rVOEK7uUKLTdb5QAcGhEVHisTGOicmoqemZHpV54NDGpiUW5VqoAMw1jj4NPHzIgiJScgrASio1Bpxo8dINCiZiuYyr1QXZPDM5h4lkx6v5AiEwpEGLtdgwgA)